# Using computed names in makefile to emulate namespaces (fx target local)

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

My idea is to use computed names to emulate namespaces, for example:

```
GetVar = $(or $($2@$1),$($2))

fubar@namespace = foo bar
frob = baz

$(info $(call GetVar,namespace,fubar))
$(info $(call GetVar,namespace,frob))
```

furthermore this could be used in rules to have target local variables

```
cmd@target = echo hello

target:
    $(call GetVar,$@,cmd)
```

This seem to work on GNU-make, but it raises a few questions:

First of all this will result in using non-normal characters in variable names. Of course one may use another separator than `@`, but in using the target name as the namespace name you would inevitably run into cases where dots and slashes end up in the variable name. How bad is this? The GNU-make manual tells me to avoid this and mentions the ability to share this via environment to submakes, but this is in a non-recursive makefile setup.

Is this exploiting a non-portable feature of GNU-make? Need I be concerned with feature versions of make breaking this feature?

Is there any example of this idiom actually being used? Not being able to find any cases makes me wonder if there's anything I've missed that makes this a bad idea.

If it's not that bad idea, are there any particular namespace separator that would be more suitable than other?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see you're mostly recreating [target-specific variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html).  Is there some reason you don't want to use them?

```
target: cmd = echo hello

target:
        $(cmd)
```